# How to return different count of multiple values from Python function

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, refactoring, iterable-unpacking

I have legacy class hierarchy which I want to extend with new class with different method signature: overrided method should return tree values instead of two. Third return value for legacy classes should be some default value. Example below ([repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/TechnologicalSeparatePreprocessor)).

```py
class BaseClass:
    def do_work(self):
        param1, param2, param3 = self.get_params()
        self._process(param1, param2, param3)

    def get_params(self):
        # this method shoud be overrided in the child class
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def _process(self, param1, param2, param3):
        # do some process, for example, print params
        print(param1, param2, param3)


class LegacyChild(BaseClass):
    def get_params(self):
        return 1, 2, 3


class NewChild(BaseClass):
    def get_params(self):
        return 1, 2


legacy_child = LegacyChild()
legacy_child.do_work()

new_child = NewChild()
new_child.do_work()
```

In this case I get `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)` on third line. And this is correct.

My first thought to solve this was to change hardcoded three params to tuple with variable length and then set `param1`, `param2` and `param3` based on it's length:

```py
class BaseClass:
    def do_work(self):
        params = self.get_params()

        if len(params) == 3:
            param1, param2, param3 = params
        else:
            param1, param2 = params
            param3 = 3  # some default value

        self._process(param1, param2, param3)

    def get_params(self):
        # this method shoud be overrided in the child class
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def _process(self, param1, param2, param3):
        # do some process, for example, print params
        print(param1, param2, param3)
```

I think that this solution is too rough ([repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LumberingBelatedLegacysystem)).

Is there any other possible solution for that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
param1, param2, *param3 = self.get_params() # param3 is an array. When there are only 2 elements, it's empty.
self._process(param1, param2, (param3 or [3])[0]) # 3 is the default value
```

This is assuming that `get_params` will always produce 2 or 3 elements. It can't be easily extended to handle methods that return only one element.

Comment: It's better than mine but not a brilliant) By the way I'll mark it as an answer ) Thanks a lot!